# How to greet with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to do this by typing my name in the input, then pressing the button and an h1 tag will appear below the input: Hello (my name)! I don't know how to solve this.

Here is my html and jQuery code:

```
<form>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="Name">
    <button id="button" type="button">Click</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $('body').append('<h1></h1>')
        $("h1").append('Hello')//+ my name
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the value of a text input? `$("#Name").val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the value from the `#Name` input. Unless you have a specific reason for doing this in multiple steps, you can append the html as a whole like this:

```html
<form>
  <label for="Name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="Name">
  <button id="button" type="button">Click</button>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#button').click(function () {
    if ($('#Name').val()) { //make sure the user entered something
      $('body').append(`<h1>Hello ${$('#Name').val()}!</h1>`);
    }
  });
</script>
```

The backticks `` are a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), they allow you to build strings without a bunch of concatenation.

`` `Hello ${my_name}!` `` vs `'Hello ' + my_name + '!'`

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of the `input` field you can use:
`$('input#Name').val();`
Instead of appending it to the `h1` element, you can simply set its text to the wanted value, in your case: `.text('hello '+getName)`.

In case a visitor makes a mistake you only need to modify the inner text of the  `h1` instead of appending it to the body again.
`$('h1').text();`

```js
$('#button').click(function () {
  let getName = $('input#Name').val();
  if(!$('h1').length){
    $('body').append('<h1 class="greeting-title"></h1>');
  }
  $("h1").text('Hello '+getName)//+ my name
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="Name">
    <button id="button" type="button">Click</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The question is how to set variable text from an input, not to check if an `<h1>` already exists. Maybe they want to add a new greeting every time the button is clicked?

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode The question isn't either if an input was set or not (as undefined won't produce an error), nor should there be an exclamation mark? Why this comment?